# SQL loop update and after update trigger with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have  Update statement and a AFTER update trigger. Update statement is happening in a loop when I am not using a  aggregate function or select on the trigger then the trigger working fine when i put  aggregate function or select then is taking the last inserted value and updating all the rows that matching to given condition

```
ALTER TRIGGER UpdateGrossPay
ON DailyClocking
AFTER UPDATE
AS
UPDATE Daily
SET GrossPay=(SELECT PayRate FROM inserted WHERE
Daily.ClockDate=inserted.ClockDate)

GO
```

I NEED the select statement because i have to use a aggregate function on it
That function is

```
SET GrossPay=((SELECT (sum(datediff(minute, 0,inserted.TotalHours))) / 60.0
FROM inserted WHERE Daily.ClockDate=inserted.ClockDate)*(SELECT PayRate from inserted))
```

Help me to do this. sorry I am new to triggers

EDIT

`ALTER TRIGGER UpdateGrossPay`
`ON DailyClocking`
`AFTER UPDATE`
`AS`
`DECLARE @rs int;`
`SET @rs=10`

`UPDATE DailyClocking`
`SET GrossPay=@rs*PayRate`
`GO`

This not need a condition to update. what ever rows updated then trigger will update the same row with that row PayRate this TRIGGER is working fine

EDIT 2

`ALTER TRIGGER GrossPay`
`ON Daily`
`AFTER UPDATE`
`AS`

`UPDATE Daily`
`SET GrossPay=(datediff(minute, 0, Daily.TotalHours) / 60.0)*Daily.PayRate`
`FROM Daily,inserted`
`WHERE`
`Daily.ClockDate=inserted.ClockDate`
`AND`
`Daily.HId=inserted.HlId`
`AND`
`Daily.RId=inserted.RId`

Comment: `...pdating all the rows that matching to given condition` Where is your condition? Your trigger will update all rows in your table.

Comment: actually it should update all the rows but it should take the same row values not last inserted

Comment: No, shouldn't. Trigger updates all table `inserted` count times.

Comment: please check my edit is working fine but when i put select on there then not

Comment: No, it can't be true. Update statement in trigger will update all rows in `DailyClocking`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update several records your trigger will fire with  several rows in "inserted" table, so you have to join your Dayly  table with inserted DailyClocking.
**In a triggger ALWAYS assume you will have several records in inserted and deleted.**
For example (perhaps you should add a join on the employee id or something accurate)

```
UPDATE Daily
SET GrossPay= (datediff(minute, 0,inserted.TotalHours) / 60.0 ) * PayRate 
FROM Daily
INNER JOIN INSERTED on Daily.ClockDate=inserted.ClockDate
and Daily.someId = inserted.SomeId  -- perhaps add some id here ? (employee or other)
```

Comment: Correct. Triggers FIRE per SQL STATEMENT, not per ROW.

Comment: There is an error coming up `Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GrossPay, Line 10
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.`

Comment: yes, I just pasted your code, and of course with sum() you would have to add a group by , but as it is already a TotalHour, I assume it is not needed, and you could remove it. I correct  my answer

Comment: ya is working but i done without join please check the EDIT on my post and i have another question i will ask after your comment Thanks.

Comment: well, it looks ok, I can't tell about your join fields becaue I don^t know your data and also I do not like old join syntax because it does not exhibit joins as clearly as ansi joins, but this is a personal preference of course :)

Comment: it reminded me that old join syntax is on deprecation list. see for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122.aspx. They may involve some "compatibility level" mode

Comment: you are very kind thanks you. Also is there any possibility trigger go wrong for a sake in my situation there are more than 200 users concurrently update this table every day, and every update have around  30 loop updates. This is the situation one stored procedure with update statement and is called on a loop in frontend asp.net

Comment: This question is too broad to answer in few lines, I would just suggest that you pay big attention to your design (cluster, indexes), to your tempdb (see MS best practices and SQLSkills site) as it used by inserted and deleted pseudo tables, and also if possible eliminate client loops as it often leads to performance issues and possible deadlocks if in transaction. If correctly done 200 users should not be a problem.